# How to automatically snap every vertices around a mesh?

Tags: modeling, snapping, retopology

I'm doing retopology on a mesh I sculpted, and sometimes certain vertices aren't placed correctly. Just moving them a tiny bit is enough for them to reposition correctly on the mesh. Is it possible to automatically 'resnap' all the vertices?